# Derivatives using fft in Matlab

Tags: fourier-series, matlab, fast-fourier-transform

I have been used matlab for two weeks and I start to appreciate its power. At the moment I am studying Fourier series in order to solve PDEs.

The exercise below asks me to find the derivate of a function using the fast fourier transform function in Matlab.

I am not able to understand where I am wrong. Thank you!

```
l= 8;    
n = 100;    
x = (linspace(0,l,n))'; 

f = @(x) x/l.*sin(10*pi*x/l);    
d_f_ex = @(x) (1/l)*sin(10*pi*x/l)+ 10*pi/(l^2)*x.*cos(10*pi*x/l);    
fval = f(x);    
ft = (1/n)*fft(f(x));    
kk = [(0:floor(n/2))';(-ceil(n/2)+1:-1)'];    
ft_d = ft.* exp(1i*2*pi*kk/l);    
d_f_rec = ifft(n*ft_d);    
%%
plot (x, d_f_ex(x), 'or', x, d_f_rec, 'ob');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I am ashamed because the first version of this answer was worst than unclear, it was not exact.

Having found meanwhile a very good answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/741238) I refer to it.
I have (slightly) adapted the code that can be found there with some supplementary explanations:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> a = 0;
> b = 8*pi;
> N = 4096;
> dx =(b-a)/N;
> t = a + dx*(0:N-1);
> f = t.*sin(t);% your function
> df1= sin(t)+t.*cos(t);% is derivative
> plot(t,df1,'b')
> fftx = fft(f);
> k = (2*pi/(b-a))*[0:N/2-1, 0, -N/2+1:-1];% "swapping"
> dffft = i*k.*fftx;% multiplication by ik
> df2 = ifft(dffft);
> plot(t,real(df2),'r'); % graphical "perfect coincidence"
> ```

Remark 1: It wasn't necessary, on the last line to take the real part. But it acts as a firewall in case imaginary parts come in for any reason.
Besides, one can check that imag(df) is identically zero ; said otherwise, plot(t,imag(df),'r') gives ... the horizontal axis.

Remark 2 : It is interesting to plot the error df1-real(df2). It is rather small, but not negligeable, in the central part and explodes at the two ends. An  interesting error analysis can be found in this question and its last answer :  (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/869197).

Remark 3: As a general rule, it's better to express the mathematical expressions like $x.*\sin(x)$ without "implementation details".

Comment: there is 'i' in my code..

Comment: why x/l in stead of kk?

Comment: The coincidence is *almost* perfect.  It's perhaps better to use a (periodic) function without jump discontinuities to avoid the Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi In the case at end, the two curves (original df and fft-computed df) are undistinguishable. But one must take care : fft is NOT a tool for Fourier expansions of periodic curves, thus no connection with Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi You are right, the coincidence is graphically perfect and "almost" perfect when you compute it. See the interesting analysis in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/869197)

Comment: I wonder whether we are looking at the same plot.  When I run your code (in MATLAB R2017a) the Gibbs phenomenon is unmistakeably present, but if I choose a function whose derivative has the same value at the beginning and at the end of the "window," then there's no problem.

Comment: The Discrete Fourier Transform (the FFT being just a clever algorithm to compute the DFT) represents a function as superposition of periodic functions.  Hence there is an implicit assumption that the function will repeat "in the next window."

Comment: @Fabio Lorenzi I appreciate your remark. You are pointing to the right condition. Though I wouldn't call it a "Gibbs phenomenon" (I would keep this name for Fourier series)

Comment: You are right in pointing out that the Gibbs phenomenon is for the Fourier Series. (The DFT of a Heaviside function exhibits no "ringing.")  However, the multiplication by $ik2\pi/T$ "trick" is for Fourier series.